# Simultaneous connection to multiple apps QBD

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have an account on intuit with 3 companies. When I want to grant access to my dev app for two companies I am only allowed to access the last one that I got access tokens for. So if I connect Company#1 I can access data fro Company#1 but if i connect Company#2 I can only access Company#2 data but not Company#1. If I request OAuth tokens for Company#1 again I can access Company#1 data but not Company#2 and I need way to access data for both companies.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Intuit Anywhere currently doesnt support multiple company files for the same user, You need a new Oauth Access token to load the blue dot menu for the company who's context you want to show.

update 11/6
This issue will be resolved in a release during the week of November  26th.